# What's the best TLD for a personal, international website?

Tags: top-level-domains, internationalization, personal-website

I'd like to register a domain for myself. On it, I'll publish SciFi stories that I'm writing. The stories will be available in English and German (the two languages that I know) but if fans want to translate them, I'm open for other languages as well.

When I read `.de`, my impression is "it's in German, only."

Which is the best TLD for a non-commercial but language agnostic site? `.info`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.com` remains the most prominent international TLD. TLDs like `.info` all feel a bit ... spammy. You may be able to overcome that but if you can find a suitable available `.com`, go with it!

`.net` may also work (although not nearly as good as `.com`).